# When the Python __call__ method gets extra first argument?

Tags: python-3.x, python-datamodel

The following sample

```
import types
import pprint
class A:
    def __call__(self, *args):
        pprint.pprint('[A.__call__] self=%r, args=%r'
                      % (self, list(args)))
class B:
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    print(callable(a))
    a(1, 2)
    b = B()
    b.meth = types.MethodType(a, b)
    b.meth(3, 4)
```

prints

```
True
'[A.__call__] self=<__main__.A object at 0xb7233c2c>, args=[1, 2]'
('[A.__call__] self=<__main__.A object at 0xb7233c2c>, args=[<__main__.B '
 'object at 0xb71687cc>, 3, 4]')
```

The number of the __call__ method arguments is changed in the
b.meth(3, 4) example. Please explain the first one (__main__.B
object...) and when Python does provide it?

Using Python 3.5.3 on Debian 9.9 Stretch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important concept here is that a class function is a function that has 'self' bound to it as its first argument.

I'll demonstrate in a couple of examples. The following code will be identical for all examples:

```
import types

# Class with function
class A:
    def func(*args):
        print('A.func(%s)'%(', '.join([str(arg) for arg in args])))

# Callable function-style class
class A_callable:
    def __call__(*args):
        print('A_callable.__call__(%s)'%(', '.join([str(arg) for arg in args])))

# Empty class
class B():
    pass

# Function without class
def func(*args):
    print('func(%s)'%(', '.join([str(arg) for arg in args])))
```

Now let's consider a couple of examples:

```
>>> func(42)
func(42)
```

This one is obvious. It just calls the function `func` with argument `42`.

The next ones are more interesting:

```
>>> A().func(42)
A.func(<__main__.A object at 0x7f1ed9ed2908>, 42)
>>> A_callable()(42)
A_callable.__call__(<__main__.A_callable object at 0x7f1ed9ed28d0>, 42)
```

You can see that the class object `self` is automatically given to the function as the first argument. It is important to note that the `self` argument is **not** added because the function is stored in an object, but because the function was *constructed* as part of the object, and therefore has the object *bound to it*.

To demonstrate:

```
>>> tmp = A().func
>>> tmp
<bound method A.func of <__main__.A object at 0x7f1ed9ed2978>>
>>> tmp(42)
A.func(<__main__.A object at 0x7f1ed9ed2978>, 42)

>>> tmp = A_callable().__call__
>>> tmp
<bound method A_callable.__call__ of <__main__.A_callable object at 0x7f1ed9ed2908>>
>>> tmp(42)
A_callable.__call__(<__main__.A_callable object at 0x7f1ed9ed2908>, 42)
```

The `self` argument does **not** get added because you write `a.` before it. It is part of the function object itself, storing it in a variable still keeps that binding.

You can also manually bind a class object to a function, like this:

```
>>> tmp = types.MethodType(func, B)
>>> tmp
<bound method func of <class '__main__.B'>>
>>> tmp(42)
func(<class '__main__.B'>, 42)
```

On the other hand, just assigning a function to a class does **not** bind `self` to the function. As previously mentioned, the argument does **not** get dynamically added when called, but statically when constructed:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.func = func
>>> b.func
<function func at 0x7f1edb58fe18>
>>> b.func(42)
func(42) # does NOT contain the `self` argument
```

That is why we need to explicitely bind `self` to the function if  we want to add it to an object:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.func = types.MethodType(func, b)
>>> b.func
<bound method func of <__main__.B object at 0x7f1ed9ed2908>>
>>> b.func(42)
func(<__main__.B object at 0x7f1ed9ed2908>, 42)
```

The only thing left is to understand how *binding* works. If a method `func` has a parameter `a` bound to it, and gets called with `*args`, it will add `a` to the *beginning* of `*args` and then pass it to the function. The *beginning* is important here.

---

Now we know everything needed to understand your code:

```
>>> a = A_callable()
>>> b = B()
>>> b.func = types.MethodType(a, b)
>>> b.func
<bound method ? of <__main__.B object at 0x7f1ed97e9fd0>>
>>> b.func(42)
A_callable.__call__(<__main__.A_callable object at 0x7f1ed97fb2b0>, <__main__.B object at 0x7f1ed97e9fd0>, 42)
```

First of all, we can change the `b.func` to plain `tmp` because, as previously discussed, adding a function to an object does not change its type or functionality. Only binding `self` does.

Then, let's step through the code piece by piece:

```
>>> a = A_callable()
>>> b = B()
```

So far so good. We have an empty object `b` and a callable object `a`.

```
>>> tmp = types.MethodType(a,b)
```

This line is the crux. If you understand this, you will understand everything.

`tmp` is now the function `a` with `b` bound to it. That means, if we call `tmp(42)`, it adds `b` to the *beginning* of its arguments. `a` will therefore receive `b, 42`. Then, because `a` is callable, it forwards its arguments to `a.__call__`.

That means, we are at the point where `tmp(42)` is equal to `a.__call__(b, 42)`.

Because `__call__` is a class function of `A_callable`, `a` is automatically bound to the `__call__` function during the construction of `a`. Therefore before the arguments reach `A_callable.__call__`, `a` gets added to the *beginning* of the argument list, meaning the arguments are now `a, b, 42`.

Now we are at the point where `tmp(42)` equals `A_callable.__call__(a, b, 42)`. This is exactly what you see:

```
>>> tmp = types.MethodType(a, b)
>>> tmp(42)
A_callable.__call__(<__main__.A_callable object at 0x7f1ed97fb2b0>, <__main__.B object at 0x7f1ed97e9fd0>, 42)
>>> A_callable.__call__(a, b, 42)
A_callable.__call__(<__main__.A_callable object at 0x7f1ed97fb2b0>, <__main__.B object at 0x7f1ed97e9fd0>, 42)
```

Now if you split your arguments into `self, *args`, you basically just take away the first argument and store it in `self`. Your first argument is `a`, so `self` will be `a`, and your other `*args` will be `b, 42`. Again, this is exactly what you see.